# Localization Support in Android

Tags: android, globalization, multilingual

In my application, I want to support Turkish along with English. My directory is as follows. I wonder should I also copy attr, colors, dimens and styles files into values-tr as well.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Android will default to the values folder for those files. This also applies to the other resource directories. See also the description [in the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch).